# What does the star with a # in your kits mean

Tags: battlefield-3

What does the dogtag shape (with a star and number in it) inbetween the kit emblem and name under main/my soldier/customize

Ex. +(*  #)assault

and dogtag shape (with a star and number in it) under neath your primary weapon, side arm and gadget one
Ex. Sidearm
.
......(*  #) M9
mean

Answer (score 4):

You earn a service star for every 100 kills with that specific gun. The number next to the Star indicates the number of times you have earned a service star. Check the battlelog.battlfield.com web site for all of your stats